# the google ads is not shows in my mobile

Tags: java, android, google-ads-api, ads

I want to use google ads and everything looks right but the ad is not showing up.
I tried this code but it doesn't seem to be working 
I downloaded the google play service sdk and I downloaded google Repository 
and I used the compile in the build.gradle
 **here is my code in manifest**

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</manifest>
```

And in the layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.joba4joo.adstist.MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the mainActivity

```
package com.joba4joo.adstist;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);}}
```

can you help me please.... thanks

Comment: not and i used the user permission  internet and access network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

in your strings.xml resource file. This allows you to use `"@string/banner_ad_unit_id"` in your layout file

Second, it seems like you are missing a line in your MainActivity. Try this

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```